# Alter Request parameter(Email) and then Authenticate User in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, illuminate

I need to change the request parameter i.e. email, and then attempt login with the new email.
What I am trying:

```
$user_handle = $request->email;
$gook = Gookarma::where('handle', '=', $user_handle)->firstOrFail();
$acc = Account::find($gook->karmable_id);
$request->email = $acc->email;
            
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

But it doesn't update the request, and login attempt goes with the previous email field input.
Previous email I'm pulling up from API.

I tried with `request->all()` but when attempt login after the request update, it displays an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new variable of Request instance and assigning email and password from the previous request variable to the new variable worked for me.

```
$req = new Request([$request]);
$req['email']=$acc->email;
$req['password'] = $request->password;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [merge](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) method :

```
$request->merge([
    'email' =>$acc->email,
]);
```

or you can build an array to replace the entire request input like:

```
$arrayToReplace=$request->all();
$arrayToReplace['email']=$acc->email;
```

and then use [replace](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L323) method:

```
 $request->replace($arrayToReplace);
```

if neither of the above ways did not work, try making a request your self:

```
 $array=$request->all();
 $array['email']=$acc->email;
 $req = new Request([$array]);
```

then use the new request for your operations.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried doing this but it isn't updating the email, I tried this 
$request = $request->all();
$request['email'] = $acc->email;
This updated the email, but on $this->attemptLogin($request) it shows error:
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::attemptLogin() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given

Comment: try the second way

Comment: It doesn't work either. Request object doesn't get updated.

Comment: do you have: use  Illuminate\Http\Request; in top of your class?

Comment: Yes I have imported

Comment: Thanks bro for the help, this updated the request variable with email, but still not accepted by $this->attemptLogin($req), Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$request->merge(['email' => $acc->email]);
```

---